# How to Integrate Payment method like Google pay, PhonePe in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, payment-gateway, android-pay, android-googleapiclient

I have tried a lot to integrate payment methods like google pay, PhonePe, and others. but couldn't able to find one proper example or Documentation. please someone explains if anyone has done it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to receive payments through UPI, [this](https://github.com/NAndroidEx/UPIPayments) is the easiest library to do so. It supports almost all UPI apps.

[image]

Comment: Thansk alot @Niraj. I will implement this